# Breakdown on a website load?

Tags: windows

My pings to sites are relatively quick:  ~6-7ms to Google.

However, when I load the actual site http://www.google.com Firefox measures it as taking 1-2 seconds on average.  In fact, most websites appear to take that long.  I've tested this with an out-of-network computer and obviously it's much faster.

Where do I start on debugging?  Is there an easy way to do a kind of a traceroute, except for on the webpages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gut tells me that this is a web content filter/cache creating your lag. Probably transparent, since you dont mention it.

Answer (score 3):

tcptraceroute can show a traceroute of TCP/UDP/ICMP requests : see [the Wikipedia page for it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcptraceroute) for an example.

You might also want to try using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) for Firefox -- it will give you a network time-line for requests and replies, showing you where those couple of seconds have gone.

Answer (score 2):

Try hitting google by IP and see if you see the same lag:

http://74.125.127.100/

If not, then you've got a DNS issue somewhere.  Check the machine's hosts file to make sure that there aren't any unexpected entries (usually from malware).